# Google App Engine cant find class Error : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, google-app-engine

created GAE Project imported all classes/Servlets..
uplodaded project to GAE Server
when i am testing Servlet inside the uploaded Server it works find but when Servlet is creating instance of one of the inner classes i get the next Error :

```
Error for /Servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : could not initialize class <my package.class>
```

newbie with GAE.
Thanx for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually an indication that you did not include the required jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder. You don't get an error because you included this jar on your class path. If it's not in the WEB-INF/lib folder, however, it will not be uploaded to App Engine.

If you use Eclipse, select your project and check the Problems tab. It may have a warning that a certain resource will not be available on the server. Right click on it and select Copy option.

Comment: Well LOL there are a lot but ill take the mongo the following classpath entry mongodb path will not be available on the server's classpath i checked the war\WEB-INF\lib and jars are there.

Comment: It can happen because you were adding it again to your class path before deleting it from the /lib folder, so the warning is about the new version of a jar while you see the old version in the folder. Another potential problem is having two versions of a jar in that folder. Clear the folder, reset the warnings, and copy the jars again.